# Angular app only shows adjusted dynamic content after refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, caching

I'm using a service(factory) to access my data on the server side, I'm using `$routeParams` to include the id to the request to the server. And this all works perfectly fine, but only the first time I run through the program, here is some of my code:

my controller:

```
klusplan.success(function(data) {
    console.log("onsucces",data);
    $scope.klusplan = data[0];
    $scope.klusplan.duratie = localStorage.getItem('Duration');
    $scope.klusplan.orderId = localStorage.getItem('klusplan');
    var tijdInUren = localStorage.getItem('Duration').split(":");
    var Uren = tijdInUren[0];
    var Minuten = tijdInUren[1];
    Uren = Uren + (Minuten / 60);

    $scope.klusplan.kosten = ($scope.klusplan.vm_kl_tarief * Uren);
});
```

my service:

```
 app.factory('klusplan', ['$http', '$routeParams', function($http, $routeParams) {
return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/getdata/klusplan.php?id='+$routeParams.klplan_id)

.success(function(data, status) {
    console.log("succes", data, status);
    return data;
})
.error(function(err) {
    return err;
}); 
}]);
```

and last but not least the route

```
.when('/klusplan/:klplan_id', {
        controller: 'KlusplanController',
        templateUrl: 'views/klusplan.html'
    })
```

I've already tried some things like:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
```

and

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
        console.log("event: ", event," next: ", next," current: ", current)
        $templateCache.remove(current.templateUrl);
});
});
```

Now the voodoo all starts when I run through my application for the second time, instead of getting the data from the server, the http request never fires. Instead it shows me the data gathered from the last time I ran through it.

I would appreciate any and all help.

Comment: What happen's if you hit cmd+Shift+R? Maybe Chrome is caching your http calls.

Comment: I'd try try to add a random value in your server call url (in `$http.get(...)`), to exclude protocol caching...

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `klusplan.success` function directly. So you will always get the already fetched data.

**If you write the factory like this:**

```
app.factory('klusplan', ['$http', '$routeParams', function($http, $routeParams) {
  return { 
    getData: function() { 
      return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/getdata/klusplan.php?id='+$routeParams.klplan_id);
    }
  };
}]);
```

**And then inside the controller:**

```
klusplan.getData().then(function(data) { ...
```

So you call everytime `$http.get` and getting new Data from the server instead of just the already successful fetched data.

Comment: Ofcourse! Not at my desk at this time but I've implemented it that way elsewhere, thanks!

Comment: Almost, you had to use $q to get at the defered result set. I made an edit, but you rejected it :/

Comment: I saw your defered, but you are actually not needing it. This concept is made over and over again. Just use your own $q.deferred in rare cases. Yhe $http.get will return a promise, with which you can call .then()